# Equal traces and similar matrix

Tags: matrices, trace, similar-matrices

I know that if matrix $a$ is similar to matrix $b$ then $\operatorname{trace} a=\operatorname{trace} b$.

Does it go to the other side?

Thanks.

Comment: See the proofs of that inclusion: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/823638/705917

Answer (score 1):

No. The matrix $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ and the null matrix are not similar.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ and and the matrix $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}-1&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$  both have trace $0$, yet are clearly not similar. Thus the answer is no.

Comment: can you please write the matrix? because I didnt understand you

Comment: @AvitalFunk Sure