# Conditions on real parameters s.t. matrix of a linear operator is symmetric; question of existence of a skew-symmetric matrix of the same operator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory

> $A(e)\in M_3(\mathbb R)$ represents $A\in L(\mathcal P_2)$ in canonic basis.
>   $$A(e)=\begin{bmatrix}-1&2&a\\1&2&c\\b&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$
>
> $(a)$ Find $a,b,c\in\mathbb R$ s.t. $A(f),$ basis $f=\{1+t,t-t^2,1+t+t^2\}$ is symmetric.
>
> $(b)$ Is there any basis $f$ s.t. $A(f)$ is skew-symmetric? Give an argument.

My attempt:

---

$(a)$
$$A(1)=\begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\\b\end{bmatrix},At=\begin{bmatrix}2\\2\\0\end{bmatrix},A\left( t^2\right)=\begin{bmatrix}a\\c\\1\end{bmatrix}$$

Since $A$ is linear, by definition:
$$A(1+t)=A(1)+At=\begin{bmatrix}1\\3\\b\end{bmatrix}$$
$$A\left(t-t^2\right)=At-A\left(t^2\right)=\begin{bmatrix}2-a\\2-c\\-1\end{bmatrix}$$
$$A(1+t+t^2)=A(1)+At+A\left(t^2\right)=\begin{bmatrix}1+a\\3+c\\b+1\end{bmatrix}$$

$$A(e')=\begin{bmatrix}1&2-a&1+a\\3&2-c&3+c\\b&-1&b+1\end{bmatrix}$$
$A(e')=A^{\tau}$ if:
$$2-a=3\implies a=-1\\1+a=b=0\\3+c=-1\implies c=-4$$

---

$(b)$ $\underline{\text{There is no basis}}$ $f$ s.t. $A(f)$ is skew-symmetric because $A(e)$ and $A(f)$ have to be similar in order to have the same characteristic polynomial. Similar matrices have equal traces, as I proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3591323/721644). Trace of a skew-symmetric matrix equals $0$ and $\operatorname{trace}(A(e))=2$.

---

Is that correct? If so, how can I improve my answer and reasoning? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you checked your solution? For instance, have you tried computing the matrix that results from substituting your derived values of the unknown and applying a change of basis to it? Hint: what basis is the vector that you computed as the value of $A(1+t)$ expressed in?

Comment: @amd, maybe I didn't understand it, but, are you refering to plugging the values I got into the initial matrix?

Comment: Indeed I am, then compute $P^{-1}AP$, where the columns of $P$ are the coordinates of the elements of $f$ relative to $e$. Is the result symmetric?

Comment: @amd, it turned out $P^{-1}AP$ isn't symmetricbecause $A$ isn't.

Comment: No, $P^{-1}AP$ isn’t symmetric because you overlooked something when you constructed $A(1+t)$ and friends. Try computing $AP$ and think about what the difference between the two expressions is in terms of changes of basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution for part (b) is fine. Let’s check part (a): Setting $$P=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1\\1&1&1\\0&-1&1\end{bmatrix}$$ with your solution we have $$P^{-1}AP = \begin{bmatrix}-1&1&0\\2&3&-1\\2&2&0\end{bmatrix},$$ which isn’t symmetric. What went wrong? Well, when you computed $A(1+t)=(1,3,b)^T$, it seems that you overlooked the fact that the right-hand side consists of the coordinates of $A(1+t)$ relative to the standard basis $e$, but you need its coordinates relative to the basis $f$ instead. The same mistake was made in computing the other two basis vector images. In effect, you solved the equation $AP=(AP)^T$ instead of the correct equation $P^{-1}AP=(P^{-1}AP)^T$.

Comment: So, the $A(e)$ actually is $[A]_f^e$ instead of $[A]_f^f$. Now, as you've already said in the comments, $\underline{\text{where the columns of}\; P \;\text{are the coordinates of the elements of}\;f\;\text{relative to}\;e}$, I can find a similar symmetric matrix by solving the correct equation. Thank your patience and for explaining in detail!

Comment: @ms._VerkhovtsevaKatya Yes, using that notation the matrix you call $A(e')$ in your question is $[A]_f^e$, but you needed to compute $[A]_f^f$ instead. Incidentally, I prefer the variant of this notation in which the “output” basis is the subscript. That makes it consistent with the notation for the coordinates of a vector—that only has an “output”—and then when you multiply you can formally “cancel” a superscript against the subscript of the next term to the right.